# python tarinfo permission bits

Tags: python, tar

I am using `tarfile` module to check the permission of the packages in my tar.gz file.
My problem are two folds.

Permission bits value are different from the value got from `ls -l` command.  From `list` command, value is `755`. But I get `488` in my program. I use the below command function -

---

```
def checkAndExtratZipFile (value,packageElementInfoList):
    try:
        tar = tarfile.open(value,"r:gz")
        for tarinfo in tar:
            global elementType

            # Populate all information about the element
            name  = tarinfo.name
            size  = tarinfo.size
            perm  = tarinfo.mode
            if tarinfo.isdir():
                eleType = elementType.Directory
            elif tarinfo.issym():
                eleType = elementType.SymbolicLink
            else:
                eleType = elementType.File

            # Populate into list        
            packageElementInfoList.append(packageElementInfo(name,eleType,perm,size))                   

        tar.close()
    except: 
        print "Verification of package %s failed.\n Reason : Not able to read contents in the tar package." % value
        sys.exit(1)
```

---

My system (working on SUSE Linux) will have packages to be verified which are created by SUSE/AIX and HP platform. So I need to verify packages built on AIX/HP/Linux platform on Linux Server. 
The permission bits of AIX/HP package on Linux is very weird.A `755` permission bit is given as `33256`.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're seeing a base-10 representation of an octal number:

```
>>> oct(488)
'0750'
```

You need to check flags using attributes on the `stat` module:

```
>>> tarinfo.mode
488
>>> tarinfo.mode & stat.S_IXGRP != 0
True
>>> tarinfo.mode & stat.S_IXOTH != 0
False
```